# Refactor a hash table solution to twoSum problem

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I try the most to solve a twoSum problem in leetcode

> Given an array of integers, return **indices** of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have **exactly** one solution, and you may not use the *same* element twice.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
>
> Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
> return [0, 1].
> ```

The plan:

1) brute force to iterate len(nums)   O(n)
2) search for target - num[i] with a hash table   O(1)

Implement

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        nums_d = {}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            nums_d.setdefault(nums[i], []).append(i)

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            sub_target = target - nums[i]
            nums_d[nums[i]].pop(0) #remove the fixer
            result = nums_d.get(sub_target)#hash table to search 

            if result: 
                return [i, result[0]]
        return []
```

I strives  hours for this solution but found that answer accepted but not passed Score 60.

> Runtime: 60 ms, faster than 46.66% of Python3 online submissions for Two Sum.
>   Memory Usage: 16.1 MB, less than 5.08% of Python3 online submissions for Two Sum.

I want to refactor the codes  so that to achieve at least faster than 60%.

Could you please provide hints?

Comment: This is better asked here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hint: Could your program handle the case [2, 2], target 4?

Answer (score 0):

Approach 3 in the "Solution" tab in the problem on LeetCode seems to be faster than 80%. Here's some incomplete code for you to fill in:

```py
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
  map = # ???
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    complement = # ???
    if complement in map:
      return # ???
    map[nums[i]] = # ???
```